# Can't make custom session save handler work(no registered method called) in centOS

Tags: php, mysql, session

I met a strange problem. The session save handler in linux can not work normally(The same code can work well in my local windows platform.). Here is my code for session save handler:

```
<?php
class session
{
  public static function init()
  {
    session_set_save_handler('session::open', 'session::close', 'session::read', 'session::write', 'session::destroy', 'session::gc');
  }

  public static function open($save_path, $session_name)
  {
     if (!is_dir($save_path)) {
            mkdir($save_path, 0777);
     }
    return true;
  }

  public static function close()
  {
    return true;
  }

  public static function read($sid)
  {
    global $db, $user;
    register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
      $user = anonymousUser($sid);
      return '';
    }
    $result = $db->query('SELECT s.data as session_data, s.* , u.* FROM users u INNER JOIN sessions s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = "' . $db->escape($sid) .
      '" AND timestamp >= ' . $db->escape(TIMESTAMP - Bl_Config::get('session.lifetime', 10800)));
    $user = $result->row();

    if ($user) {
      $data = $user->session_data;
      unset($user->passwd, $user->session_data);
      if ($user->uid > 0 && $user->status == 1) {
        $userInstance = User_Model::getInstance();
        $user->roles = $userInstance->getUserRoles($user->uid);
        $user->roles[] = User_Model::ROLE_AUTHENTICATED_USER;
        $user->permissions = array();
        $user->data = (isset($user->data) && $user->data) ? unserialize($user->data) : array();
        foreach ($user->roles as $rid) {
          $user->permissions = array_merge($user->permissions, $userInstance->getRolePermissions($rid));
        }
        $user->permissions = array_unique($user->permissions);
      } else {
        $user = anonymousUser($sid);
      }
      return $data;
    } else {
      $user = anonymousUser($sid);
      return '';
    }
  }

  public static function write($sid, $data)
  {
    global $db, $user;
    if (!isset($user) || ($user->uid == 0 && empty($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && empty($data))) {
      return true;
    }
    $uri = '/' . Bl_Core::getUri();
    $db->exec('UPDATE sessions SET uid = ' . $db->escape($user->uid) . ', ip = "' . $db->escape(ipAddress()) .
      '", uri = "' . $db->escape($uri) . '", data = "' . $db->escape($data) . '", timestamp = ' .
      $db->escape(TIMESTAMP) . ' WHERE sid = "' . $db->escape($sid) . '"');
    if (!$db->affected()) {
      $db->exec('INSERT IGNORE INTO sessions (sid, uid, ip, uri, data, timestamp) VALUES ("' . $db->escape($sid) .
        '", ' . $db->escape($user->uid) . ', "' . $db->escape(ipAddress()) . '", "' . $db->escape($uri) . '", "' .
        $db->escape($data) . '", ' . $db->escape(TIMESTAMP) . ')');
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static function destroy($sid)
  {
    global $db;
    $db->exec('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE sid = "' . $db->escape($sid) . '"');
    return true;
  }

  public static function gc($lifetime)
  {
    global $db;
    $db->exec('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE timestamp < ' . $db->escape(TIMESTAMP - Bl_Config::get('session.lifetime', 10800)));
    return true;
  }

  public static function count($timestamp = 0, $hasAnonymous = true)
  {
    global $db;
    if (!$hasAnonymous) {
      $cond = ' AND uid > 0';
    } else {
      $cond = '';
    }
    $result = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(0) FROM sessions WHERE timestamp > ' . $timestamp . $cond);
    return $result->one();
  }
}
```

Here is the way I call the session save handler:

```
session::init();
session_start();
```

But no method was called in the static class session. And seems the app stopped to go on after the session_start() called.

The php version I used is `PHP Version 5.1.6`.I don't know whether it's related to php.ini or some privilege for db caused such problems? I'm using the root db user and the connection was already set...

Here is php.ini settings for session(per Mike Purcell's suggestion, I've changed the session.save_path from "/var/lib/php/session" to "/tmp"):

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/tmp"
session.use_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor     = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = 0
session.bug_compat_warn = 1
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

And the error message is:
`Fatal error: session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: /tmp)`

Please help, thanks!

Comment: I'm using a virtual host in linux, but I compare `phpInfo()` between my windows settings and linux settings, I found the option for `Virtual Directory Support`is `disabled`, will that matter, if so, how can I change it to `enabled`?

Answer (score 1):

Finally after endless debug and environment change I got the solution!!!

I found It's the php version's problem. The CentOS VPS use `Cent OS 5.5` and `PHP 5.1.6` as default, but it has problem for supporting custom session save handlers. It's weird that no one and no doc mentioned this!!! My suggestions is using PHP Version 5.2.6 or later to use such feature.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. Should have realized there may have been an issue with PHP version, although most of us assume everyone is on 5.3.10+ by now, some are even on 5.4.

Comment: Thanks for your help through this issue Mike!

Comment: @nemozhp: The source of this support and documentation problem here is with CentOS.  I believe Centos 5 default repos provide up to 5.3.3.  Centos 6 repos provide only up to 5.3.6, if I recall.  The packages you want are prefixed with "php53-", _not_ the older "php-" packages, which are actually just PHP 5.2.  PHP 5.2 is more or less no longer supported by PHP.

Comment: @nemozhp: to add, if you are programming for PHP 5.1, you are 6 1/2 years behind.  If for PHP 5.2, you are 5 1/2 years behind.  Since then, several bugs, security holes, and enhancements have been made that could actually cripple your app if you suddenly upgrade.  So, although upgrading beyond 5.3.6 and even 5.4.1 is ultimately the best idea going forward to maintain a modern and healthy website, you should be careful and test/fix everything in a separate dev host first as it could break your entire code base.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer: Thanks for the comments, i was just using a vps (myhosting) which use php 5.1 as it's default settings. I just switched another vps, that's a wisdom choice.